# How to allow users to define accessible pages for their sub-users/agents?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, roles

I'm using `ASP.Net MVC` for web development. Currently my website's users are authorized based on their roles when accessing controller's actions.

Each user can define sub-users or agents and allow them to access a subset of actions he/she already has access to. For example user `A` has access to actions `{a, b, c}`. Now he wanna define agents `B` and `C` and grant them to access actions `{a}` and `{b, c}` respectively.

Considering that action names can change during development, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give them the roles to access the action.

E.g you have roles a, b, c and your have action One, Two, Three.

Use the Authorize attribute to decorate action One giving it access to role a only. Do same for the other actions like below

```
[Authorize(Roles = "a")]
public ActionResult One()
{
 return View();
}

[Authorize(Roles = "b")]
public ActionResult Two()
{
 return View();
}

[Authorize(Roles = "c")]
public ActionResult Three()
{
 return View();
}
```

This implies your user A has roles(a,b,c). To create user B and C.
Give user B role a, Give user C role b and c.

Whenever you change your action names so long as the roles remain the same. The users can still access it.

Comment: So for every action I should define a new role. I think this could result in large number of roles and large number of records in UserRoles table. On the other hand, naming these roles might be a hard work.

Comment: Your question talked about roles per action. You can use roles at the controller level to control access to all actions on a controller. You can also use roles to control access to a particular area of your application.